# How do I define multiple indices for the same set in python? (using CPLEX to solve a MILP)

Tags: modeling, python, docplex

I am using docplex in Python to solve a MILP and I am having some trouble defining the indices and sets of my model.

I want to translate $w,v,a\in W$ into Python.

In this case, $W$ is a set, and $w, v$, and $a$ are indices of this set. I found a way to define one index for a set but I don't know how to define multiple indices for the same set.

I defined the set $W$ like this:

```
n=3
W = [j for j in range(1,n+1)]
```

Then I defined the variable: $Y_{ijws}^{Dt}$ like this:

```
Y_Dt_ijws_scope = [(t,i,j,w,s) for t in T for i in I for j in J for w in W for s in S]

Y_Dt_ijws = m.integer_var_dict(Y_Dt_ijws_scope, name='Y_Dt_ijws')
```

Where $t$ belongs to a set $T$, $i$ belongs to a set $I$, etc. I defined these sets previously as I did for $W$.

This was working fine until I had to write this part of a constraint:
$$\sum_{i\in I}Y_{ijws}^{Dt}+\sum_{i\in I}\sum_{a\in W}Y_{ijas}^{Dt}\cdot S_{aw}$$

We can see that the constraint uses the variable that I defined but also uses a variable with the index $a$ instead of the index $w$, which is not defined.

I started to write the constraint like this:

```
m.add_constraints((m.sum(Y_Dt_ijws[t,i,j,w,s] for i in I) + m.sum(m.sum(Y_Dt_ijvs[t,i,j,a,s]*S_aw for a in W) for i in I))*S_DC_wv
```

But obviously, there's an error saying there is an undefined name `Y_Dt_ijvs` because I used $a$ inside the parenthesis the second time I wrote that variable.

I'm new to all this so I don't know if the way I did things is the best one. I thought of defining `Y_Dt_ijas` as a new variable but for me, that doesn't make sense since it is referring to the exact same thing. Can someone help me, please?

(P.S.: I know some people use GAMS or other things to solve these MILP problems but I have to use Python.)

Comment: Try something like this in your second term: `m.sum(Y_Dt_ijvs[t,i,j,a,s]*S_aw for i in I for a in W)*S_DC_wv` (assuming you iterate over all the `j, w, s, t`

Comment: @EhsanK I'm sorry, I don't know if I understand your suggestion. You are telling me to remove a sum? The whole constraint is `m.add_constraints((m.sum(Y_Dt_ijws[t,i,j,w,s] for i in I) + m.sum(m.sum(Y_Dt_ijvs[t,i,j,a,s]*S_aw for a in W) for i in I))*S_DC_wv == m.sum(Y_DCt_jkwvs[t,j,k,w,v,s] for k in K) for j in J for w in W for t in T for s in S)` so in the end I iterate for all those indices right?

Comment: You don't need to write `m.sum()` multiple times for summing over each index. Bring the indexes you are summing over inside of the loop. Like a comprehension. That's what I did. I brought the two indexes you are summing over (`I` and `W`) inside of the `m.sum()`.

Comment: Ok, got it! Thanks! But that doesn't solve my problem with indices. Right know I have this constraint `m.add_constraints(m.sum(Y_Dt_ijws[t,i,j,w,s] for i in I) + m.sum(Y_Dt_ijvs[t,i,j,a,s]*S_aw for a in W for i in I)*S_DC_wv == m.sum(Y_DCt_jkwvs[t,j,k,w,v,s] for k in K) for j in J for w in W for t in T for s in S)` and the same error (`name 'Y_Dt_ijvs' is not defined`).

Comment: Have you defined `Y_Dt_ijws`, `Y_Dt_ijvs`, `Y_DCt_jkwvs` all as variables? Because the terms in `add_constraints` should be either variables or constants.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! I thought I was using only variables that I had already defined but I noticed that I was writing `Y_Dt_ijvs` with a _v_ instead of a _w_ and that variable was not defined. So now I think it works, using always the same variable and switching the index when needed. Thanks for the help!